Define the size of a MDList with Kivy
I am trying to create an MDList with python but it always has the same size. I would like to create a BoxLayout to put the list inside, with the specific dimensions(width:half screen and height: Scroll view)
I tried to do something like that:
 self.contenedor_mario = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical',pos_hint={"center_x": 0.55, 'center_y':      
                                                                                                 1.1},
                                          size_hint_x= 1, size_hint_y= None,
                                          height= 460, width=1)

        

self.list_mario = MDList(pos_hint={"center_x": 0.55, 'center_y': 0.9},
                                  size_hint_x= 1, size_hint_y= None,
                                  height= 460, width=250)

for i in range(len(lista_mario)):   
    items = OneLineListItem(text=lista_mario_conceptos[i]+ '.  '+lista_mario[i] + ' €')
    self.list_mario.add_widget(items)
    
self.Scroll = ScrollView()

self.contenedor_mario.add_widget(self.list_mario)
self.Scroll.add_widget(self.contenedor_mario)

self.add_widget(self.list_mario)

